# It is really necessary to put the ? operator on every attribute of an optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

I have been working using optional chaining, but it looks like its enough by putting the ? operator on the penultime attribute to check the entire chain, what you think guys?

In order to check the entire chain would be enough by using the optional chaining like this: `data.attr1.attr2?.attr3`, or do i still need to put the ? operator on every attribute like this: `data?.attr1?.attr2?.attr3` ?

Comment: You only need to use it on nullable properties, or properties that could potentially be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: The optional chaining `?.` stops the evaluation if the value before `?.` is undefined or null and returns undefined.

Comment: Depending on the context I would personally normalize the data structure, such that you can navigate though it without optional chaining. This allows you to completely remove optional chaining from the actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

If every part of the chain could independently be `null` or `undefined`, then you need to put the `?.` operator on every part to avoid a `TypeError`.

Your example of `data.attr1.attr2?.attr3` throws a `TypeError` if either `data` or `data.attr1` are `null` or `undefined`. It returns `undefined` if `data.attr1` is set but `data.attr1.attr2` is not.

Try it out yourself:

```js
var data = undefined;
try {
  console.log(data.attr1.attr2?.attr3);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error!');
}

data = { attr1: undefined }
try {
  console.log(data.attr1.attr2?.attr3);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error!');
}

data = { attr1: { attr2: undefined } }
try {
  console.log(data.attr1.attr2?.attr3);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error!');
}
```